# What's a good idiom to describe someone who is very clever?

Tags: word-choice, idiom-requests

Is there an idiom to describe someone who is clever and quick-witted?

Comment: There are hundreds of expressions, could you whittle  down your request? Are you looking for a positive or negative expression? Formal or slang? Funny or insulting? Complimentary or derogatory/pejorative?

Comment: No reply? Then I'll presume the OP has vanished into thin air, and recommend that users close this question as being too broad.

Comment: Related: **1.** [What is a word in English that means “able to learn new things quickly”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/23014/what-is-a-word-in-english-that-means-able-to-learn-new-things-quickly) **2** [What's a word to describe someone who thinks quick?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/269334/whats-a-word-to-describe-someone-who-thinks-quick) **3** [Word for someone seeming deep and intelligent, but not really being that](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/202697/word-for-someone-seeming-deep-and-intelligent-but-not-really-being-that/202719#202719)

Comment: **4** [A single word that means “mental reaction speed”?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251337/a-single-word-that-means-mental-reaction-speed). **5** [A positive way to describe a know it all](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/126472/a-positive-way-to-describe-a-know-it-all). **6** [A laudatory expression for an expert in grammar](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/233483/a-laudatory-expression-for-an-expert-in-grammar?lq=1)

Comment: **6** [An idiom to describe someone who thinks he/she is wiser than others](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97604/an-idiom-to-describe-someone-who-thinks-he-she-is-wiser-than-others). **7** [classy sassy and a bit smart assy](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/266604/classy-sassy-and-a-bit-smart-assy). **8** [Pejorative term for graduate student](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/251084/pejorative-term-for-graduate-student)

Answer (score 1):

A common idiom is : ***(as) sly as a fox*** and (cunning as a fox:)

> - Cliché smart and clever.
>
>   - *My nephew is as sly as a fox. You have to be cunning as a fox to outwit me.*

McGraw-Hill Dictionary of American Idioms and Phrasal Verbs.